# Ubuntu(Mini) - How to replace the shell of system message dialogs with my own version?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, gtk, openbox, gtk2

I'm using **Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** installed on **VirtualBox** using mini .iso and trying to make my own distribution based on it. I know, support of that version ends in 3-4 months, I'll update it on my new computer. Of course, I'm developing desktop environment, taskbar, etc. <del>But I don't know how to customize the **message dialogs** (error, warning, question and information) of it</del>. Now I want to replace the shell of these dialogs with my own version. I'm using "**Openbox**" as base for desktop environment. And **x11** and **GTK** is installed on it. Are these message dialogs related to GTK or X11?

*(Note : This is my first question in StackExchange)*

Comment: Why do you want to customize these dialogs? For what purpose and audience?

Comment: @basile-starynkevitch Thank you for your answer. I don't like the design of dialogs and I want to make my own design for my distribution. I'm developing everything with Pascal/Lazarus IDE and I'm wondering if I can make an widget or something else that can display error, warning, etc. messages which sent from applications.

Comment: Don't comment your own question, but do [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/484386/edit) it to improve it

Comment: How many months or years of work can you afford spending? BTW, you just need a [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) and a lot of work. Lazarus IDE is for Pascal, but most of the programs involved are in C or C++. I recommend [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) but what you need the most is a lot of time (the actual choice of IDE or editor is not important)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch approximately, 4 months...

Comment: 4 months might not be enough. You could need 4 years or even more.

Comment: And (depending on what your actual goals are) you might even need more than a lifetime. Please **edit your question** to explain what you really want to do!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch edited.

Comment: Even with the recent edit, I still don't understand what you really want to do. But my current guess is that your lifetime is not enough. Please explain more precisely what you *really* want to do, and study the source code of some *existing* GTK application (and of GTK libraries) that makes you unhappy

Comment: Explain in several paragraphs what you mean by "I want to replace the shell of these dialogs with my own version". Learn first how to code a simple GTK program. Study the source code of existing ones.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I meant the executable file of these dialogs by saying "shell". And by the way I think it's possible to write GTK program with Lazarus.

Comment: Yers, you need any kind of editor to write GTK programs. If you want to keep Lazarus, please do (the editor you are using is not important; what is important is your developer's skills and knowledge; and the tone of your question makes me believe that you need to spend months in studying and reading more).

Comment: Big confusion: a dialog don't have an  executable. A GUI program using GTK is making dialogs and doing many other things.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch then I must recompile GTK

Comment: Not only GTK, but all the software using it that you feel is relevant. E.g. most of GNOME. And recompilation is the *easiest* part of the work. Understanding source code takes much more time! I *strongly* recommend writing your own GTK application (even a "hello world" like one) to understand how things work. Then *study the source code* of the programs you want to improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message dialogs are often part of the software packages. If a software is coded in C or C++, the message is generally inside its [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code), and it appears in the binary executable (use the [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) utility to check).

The widget appearance could be driven by GUI [themes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_(computing)) and styles. For GTK3, read about [GtkStyleContext](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html) etc... And Qt has its [styling tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylingtutorials.html).

**Ubuntu is mostly made of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)**. So **you can** (under specific conditions; study the [open source license](https://opensource.org/licenses) relevant for each package) **download, study, and modify the source code of programs, and redistribute improved binaries** (you generally should publish your improvements on source code). Start by [downloading](https://www.gtk.org/download/) (then compiling and studying) the source code of GTK.

Most, but not all, programs are using [internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) facilities to adapt to various human languages (e.g. English, French, Chinese, etc...). In practice, see [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) and [gettext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gettext.3.html) and read the [message translation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Message-Translation.html) chapter of GNU glibc documentation.

[GTK](https://gtk.org/) contains [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib) (and also GDK, which interfaces to X11) which has its [internationalization macros](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-I18N.html).

[Qt](https://qt.io/) documents its [Internationalization](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html) facilities.

My recommendation might be to either have your own message catalog (see [msgfmt(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/msgfmt.1.html)...), or perhaps compile the distribution from source code which you might patch.

BTW, your project is much more ambitious than what you might believe. I strongly recommend installing Linux natively on your laptop (outside of any VirtualBox, directly on the hardware, in several dedicated disk partitions) and taking weeks to become more familiar with it.

At last, Ubuntu 14 is really old. Consider basing your work on a more recent Ubuntu, e.g. Ubuntu 18.04 (in november 2018). You could get more help.

You might be interested by [linuxfromscratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) or by source based Linux distributions such as [Gentoo](https://www.gentoo.org/) or [Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/).

> Now I want to replace the shell of these dialogs with my own version.

So you need to patch the source code of relevant programs. You may want to search for occurrences of [`gtk_dialog_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html) or of [`gtk_message_dialog_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMessageDialog.html#gtk-message-dialog-new)  and *related* functions. You should learn how to [get started with GTK](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/gtk-getting-started.html), focus on one program at first (e.g. if you want to improve [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit), get its source code and compile then study it), and improve it.

> I'm using "Openbox" as base for desktop environment

Then [download](http://openbox.org/wiki/Openbox:Download) the source code of [Openbox](http://openbox.org); study it. Be aware of [EWMH](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) conventions. I'm sure the OpenBox community will welcome your efforts (if your contributions are open source).

> Are these message dialogs related to GTK or X11?

Read more about [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), its [protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol), [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server), [ICCCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Client_Communication_Conventions_Manual), [Gnome](https://www.gnome.org/). All of them (when it is software) are free software, and well documented (but you'll need to read many thousands of pages).

The dialogs  (of programs built above GTK) are generally using the [GtkDialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html) class (or subclasses), in the Glib/[GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/index.html) sense of classes.

PS. **What you want to achieve** (which is *unclear* to me) **could take you many months or *years* of work** (perhaps even more than a lifetime). However, if you just want to make a new theme, or a new message catalog, that could just take you weeks.

PPS. Be aware that a Linux distribution has several dozens of billions of source code lines. Your lifetime (even if you live a thousand years) is not enough to study all of them, and your brain is not powerful enough to understand all of them. So focus on a small subpart. Start by downloading some source code and compiling it, then studying it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86322/discussion-on-answer-by-basile-starynkevitch-ubuntumini-how-to-replace-the-s).